# Sum of nulls to return null

Tags: arangodb, aql

How to make 
`sum(array[*].value)` to return NULL if all values are NULL or no values?

Currently it returns 0 in both cases

The best I can think of is

```
first_document(array[*].value) ? sum(array[*].value) : null
```

which needs to iterate collection twice

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a FOR loop instead of the shorthand notation and filter out null values? Then we can check if zero elements remain and return null:

```
LET tmp = (FOR elem IN array FILTER elem.value != null RETURN elem)
RETURN LENGTH(tmp) ? SUM(tmp) : null
```

You could also use an [array inline expression](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/AQL/Advanced/ArrayOperators.html#inline-expressions), but it's about the same amount of characters:

```
LET tmp = arr[* FILTER CURRENT.value != null RETURN CURRENT.value]
RETURN LENGTH(tmp) ? SUM(tmp) : null
```